# Проверка элемента в списке py json

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(view_audit_log=True)
async def clear(ctx, amount: int):
    with open ('logsserver.json', 'r') as f:
        channels = json.load(f)
    lol = channels[str(ctx.guild.id)]
    ch = client.get_channel(lol)

    if amount <= 0:
        b = discord.Embed(title='Ошибка!', color=0xff060e)
        b.add_field(name='Причина ошибки:', value='Нельзя удалять 0 и меньше сообщений!', inline=False)
        await ctx.send(embed=b)
    if amount >=1000:
        b = discord.Embed(title='Ошибка!', color=0xff060e)
        b.add_field(name='Причина ошибки:', value='Нельзя удалять 1000 и больше сообщений!', inline=False)
        await ctx.send(embed = b)
    if amount > 0 and amount <1000:
        await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount)
        a = discord.Embed(title='Очистка чата', color=0xd6b0b1)
        a.add_field(name='Чат очищен!', value=f'Было удалено {amount} сообщений администратором / модератором {ctx.author.name}')
        a.set_footer(text=f'Вызвано: {ctx.message.author}', icon_url=ctx.message.author.avatar_url)
        await ctx.send(embed=a, delete_after = 10 )
        await ch.send(embed = a)
```

Мне нужно чтобы если в переменной lol нету значения, то бот отправляет в чат сообщение об ошибке.

Answer (score 0):

Просто сделайте проверку на значение:

```
if channels["lol"] == "":
    await ctx.send("Error message")
```

Если вам не понятен синтаксис, `==` - оператор сравнения(если равно).